# How do I add a field in Google Forms to show the sum of multiple fields (that are numbers)

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Say for instance I want the user to input into 4 fields the meters they will dig up in different areas. On the form itself I would like to have a number at the bottom displaying the sum of 3 of said fields.

Is this possible? If it is, how do I go about getting it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Forms doesn't include calculated fields. One alternative is to create a web app by using [Google Apps Scripts](https://www.google.com/script/start/).

Comment: Thanks Ruben! I thought this might be the case here, was trying to avoid creating an app.